# how to use OR/AND operator together in sql ?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having issues getting this query to work, i am actually trying to use the OR and AND operator together but can't seem to figure out the problem as to why i am getting this error": `"expecting`ABSOLUTE' or `ACTION' or`ADD' or `ALL' or`ALTER'"`.  Here is my sql code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EDXW ED, TRANSACTION TXN
WHERE ED.LAM_BK like 'TAR%'
AND ED.KEY = TXN.KEY
AND substring(ED.JAM_BK from position('~' in ED.JAM_BK) + 1) = TXN.EBS_ID

(AND ED.CLS_CD IN ('WIS','OP','OPP')
AND TXN.REV_CD IN ('0360','0361')
AND TXN.LS_CTR_CD IN ('548000','552000','552500','553000','553500','554000','555000','555500','558000')
AND ED.SITE_CD = 'X' )

OR

( ED.ED_CLS_CD IN ('WIS','OP','OPP')
AND AND TXN.REV_CD IN ('0350','0311')
AND AND TXN.LS_CTR_CD IN ('548000','558300')
AND LOC.ED_SITE_CD = 'M')

OR

( ED.ED_CLS_CD IN ('WIS','OP','OPP')
AND AND TXN.REV_CD IN ('0350','0311')
AND AND TXN.LS_CTR_CD IN ('549000','557300')
AND LOC.ED_SITE_CD IN ('M','K'));
```

Comment: You have `AND AND` in several places in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you say: `a and b and c and d or e or f` but I think you want to say `a and b and c and (d or e or f)` which is something very different. The whole expression becomes true when f is true or e is true. The braces make it clear. I think your select has to look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EDXW ED, TRANSACTION TXN
WHERE ED.LAM_BK like 'TAR%'
AND ED.KEY = TXN.KEY
AND substring(ED.JAM_BK from position('~' in ED.JAM_BK) + 1) = TXN.EBS_ID
AND
(
 (ED.CLS_CD IN ('WIS','OP','OPP')
 AND TXN.REV_CD IN ('0360','0361')
 AND TXN.LS_CTR_CD IN ('548000','552000','552500','553000','553500','554000','555000','555500','558000') 
 AND ED.SITE_CD = 'X' )

OR

 ( ED.ED_CLS_CD IN ('WIS','OP','OPP')
 AND TXN.REV_CD IN ('0350','0311')
 AND TXN.LS_CTR_CD IN ('548000','558300')
 AND LOC.ED_SITE_CD = 'M')

OR

 ( ED.ED_CLS_CD IN ('WIS','OP','OPP')
 AND TXN.REV_CD IN ('0350','0311')
 AND TXN.LS_CTR_CD IN ('549000','557300')
 AND LOC.ED_SITE_CD IN ('M','K'))
);
```

Comment: No.  The problem is the original poster wrote a and b (and c) instead of a and b and (c).  (Your edit address this)

Comment: Actually, it does apply.  Your code is correct after editing, but your explanation still isn't.  Your "a and b" logic in the sentence isn't equivalent to what the poster wrote.

Answer (score 3):

You've got extra parens or missing and/ors.  Here's a simplified version that shows the problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tables
WHERE clause1
(AND clause2)
```

From SQL's point of view, this is incorrect.  Possible correct versions are

```
SELECT * 
FROM tables
WHERE clause1
AND (clause2)

SELECT * 
FROM tables
WHERE clause1
OR (clause2)
```

See the difference?  The parens group statements.  So you can have more complex expressions like:
    SELECT * 
    FROM tables
    WHERE clause1
    AND (clause2 or clause3)

They key is that if you were to reduce everything in the parens to a single true/false value, the query would still make sense.